# MySQL query returns empty resultset

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

Currently I'm writing a very simple Java Servlet which will only execute one query and print the results.

The issue I'm facing is that it's working locally using JBoss as AS. When I deploy it to TomCat remotely, the same query is returning no results.

My observations:

- The table has data. I've used SQuirrelSQL to check (about 100 rows);
- Using the mysql cli it is also returning no results;
- The code below returns "yes yes yes yes..." locally, but remotely only "go"

The code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(res.getWriter());
    }

    List<Opportunity> opportunityList = new ArrayList<Opportunity>();

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname", "dbuser", "dbpwd");
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(QUERY);
        while(rs.next()) {
            res.getWriter().print("yes ");
            opportunityList.add(new Opportunity(rs));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        opportunityList.clear();
        res.getWriter().print("nooo ");
        res.getWriter().println(e.toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            res.getWriter().write("go ");
            conn.close();
            st.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            res.getWriter().write("noooo2");
            res.getWriter().println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    res.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(opportunityList));

}
```

EDIT-- The query:

```
SELECT o.ID, o.NAME, s.DESCRIPTION, pt.NAME, o.START_DATE, so.OWNER, 
FROM SCOUT_OPPORTUNITY so 
INNER JOIN OPPORTUNITY o ON so.OPPORTUNITY_ID = o.ID 
INNER JOIN STATUS_DESC s ON s.NAME = o.STATUS_NAME 
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_TYPE pt ON pt.ID = o.PROJECT_TYPE_ID 
ORDER BY o.ID
```

Comment: Change `catch(SQLException e)` to `catch(Exception e)` to see if you are hitting an exception...then print out that exception or log it so you know what the problem is

Comment: We need more information to be able to help you full code, query etc...

Comment: Maybe a hint: "localhost" / "When I deploy it to TomCat remotely"

Comment: I have changed catch(SQLException e) to catch(Exception e) and still no exception.

Comment: There is a mysql server running on the remote server. Otherwise the mysql cli won't be available.

Comment: I've added the query

Comment: You say there is data in "the table". Which of them? There must be data in `SCOUT_OPPORTUNITY`, `OPPORTUNITY`, and `STATUS_DESC`, and there should probably be data in `PROJECT_TYPE` as well although lack of it would not cause the query to return no rows.

Comment: Let's just say that `SELECT * FROM SCOUT_OPPORTUNITY;` in the cli is giving me a empty resultset too.

Comment: I'm sorry to have waisted your time. I found out the database name is not the same on the remote machine but it DOES exists. Let's just be very gratefull this sort of irregularities are sooooo wel documented.